# How to know js is ready to receive events from native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm working on a react native android app. I'm issuing a notification from a background service (which runs even if the app is closed) when the service finishes its job. When the notification is tapped it starts the app and sends an event to JS from a native module.

What happens is that when I close the app and tap the notification, the app starts, the event is sent from the native module, but is not received by the JS side. I have verified that it is received when I don't close the app.

The problem is that event is fired before the JS side is subscribed for the event (I'm subscribing at the earliest moment possible). In a native module, is there a way to find out if js has started (and is ready to receive event) and issue it after that, or do I have to go the other way (ask the native module from js)? Didn't find this anywhere in the docs.
Thanks!